# How do the Fermi level, HOMO and LUMO change with doping?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, fermions, orbitals

I am a bit confused about solid state physics of organic materials because as I know the workfunction changes with the doping of a material but the Fermi level is constant with doping. So depend on the formula: 
$$W=E_v-E_f$$
where $W$ is workfuntion, $E_f$ is the Fermi level and $E_v$ is the vacuum level, either the $E_f$ or $E_v$ should change. So if the $E_f$ does not change with doping, $E_v$ should change. And we know that $A_f$ (electron affinity) remains constant with doping and:
$$A_f=E_v-\text{LUMO}$$
So the LUMO (Lowest Unoccupied Molecular Orbital) should also change with doping to have a constant $A_f$. What about HOMO (Highest Occupied Molecular Orbital)? Does it change with doping because of constant $E_g$ (band gap) or not? Can some one help me to have the right understanding?

Comment: Why is the Fermi level constant with doping? This is the level of 50% occupancy; this should change with doping.

Comment: So you mean the Fermi level changes with doping. Well I do not have good reference for this idea. I read about 20 academic articles about organic electronics but there were no clear idea about it, So I have to just rely on some articles and Wikipedia.

Comment: If you provide some references that mention constant fermi-level we can probably tease this apart.

Comment: Well I meant that I do not have good reference that Fermi level remains constant with doping. :) Do you have a reference that says it changes with doping? Normally your argument is right. because by doping, either adding electrons or deducting electrons, total electron energy should change. In this case work function should also change with doping.